# Expectation of a transformation of a random variable

Tags: probability

I have a random variable $X$ which is Gaussian and I know the expected value, say $$\mathbb{E}[X] = M.$$ Is there smart way of computing $\mathbb{E}[\exp(X)]$ ? The same problem applies to the variance; i.e. I want to compute $\mathbb{V}\mbox{ar}[\exp(X)]$ and I already know $\mathbb{V}\mbox{ar}[X]$ = V.

Comment: Disappointing of course, but the answer is: "no".

Comment: You would need either all moments or samples. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_%28mathematics%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except in the Gaussian case, there is no straight-forward link between $\mathbb{E}[X],\mathbb{V}\text{ar}[X]$ and $\mathbb{E}[\exp(X)]$ and $\mathbb{V}\text{ar}[\exp(X)]$

In the gaussian case i.e $X$ being a normal gaussian law with mean $\mu$ and variance $V$, you have :

$$\mathbb{E}[\exp(X)]=\exp(\mu+\frac{1}{2}V)$$
$$\mathbb{V}\text{ar}[\exp(X)]=\mathbb{E}[\exp(2X)]-\mathbb{E}[\exp(X)]^2=e^{2\mu+\frac{1}{2}4V}-e^{2\mu+\frac{1}{2}2V}$$

Comment: Why is the Gaussian case any different?

Comment: Actually $X$ is Gaussian; a pretty vital detail I didn't supply. I will update my answer, and thank you! Do you know where to find some literature on this?

Comment: In the gaussian case, Laplace transform is expressed as a function of mean and variance.
you might have other distribution where it is the same (I think about the Bernouilli case for example). But it is a **no** in generality.

Comment: look at wikipedia : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Examples

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure there isn't any formula to compute $\mathbb E(f(X))$ given  $\mathbb E(X)$.

At the very least, for a convex function such as $\exp$ you have the jensen inequality, so $f(\mathbb E(X))\leqslant\mathbb E(f(X))$.

Now if $X$ has density $p$ you can try and calculate the integral :

$$\mathbb{E}[f(X)]=\int_\mathbb{R}e^up(u)du$$

(which by the way is the Laplace transform in 1.)